# How to force ld to use a static lib instead of shared lib?

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I am trying to build by source using the static version of the test library. I have both libtest.a and libtest.so available, so I am using the "-static" option. However, It looks like the gcc linker is also trying to search for static version the standard math library.
Any idea what option I can use to link the shared versions of the standard libraries?

```
g++ -static main.cpp -o a.out -L. -ltest
```

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
```

Comment: Do you have libtest.so in current directory?

Comment: yes i do have both libraries in the current directory

Comment: Do you have the static version of the math library somewhere, i.e. libm.a?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Also. "g++ main.cpp -o a.out -L. -ltest" works fine but then the shared version of the test library is linked into the executable. I want to link against the static libtest.a

Comment: You need to install them -- best on the system level if you have the necessary permissions. Package managers do this (e.g. on Fedora `sudo yum install glibc-static`).

Comment: Your using the `-static` options means it tries to link everything statically, including libm and libc.

Comment: Oh.. So is there no way in gcc to link against the static version of one library and the shared version of the another library.

Comment: Great. Thanks jogojapan. The "-Wl,-Bdynamic" option works perfectly.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of "cannot find -lc and -lm in g++ linux" even if the title was nearly the same. I've changed the title to be possibly be more descriptive of the actual question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to force the linker to use the static version of a particular library you can use the `:filename` to force a particular library instead of just giving the linker a 'base' library name and letting it use the first one it finds:

```
g++ main.cpp -o a.out -l:./libtest.a
```

From http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.23.1/ld/Options.html:

> ```
> -l namespec
> --library=namespec
> ```
>
> Add the archive or object file specified by `namespec` to the list of
>   files to link. This option may be used any number of times. If
>   `namespec` is of the form `:filename`, ld will search the library path for
>   a file called `filename`, otherwise it will search the library path for
>   a file called `libnamespec.a`.
>
> On systems which support shared libraries, ld may also search for
>   files other than `libnamespec.a`. Specifically, on ELF and SunOS
>   systems, ld will search a directory for a library called
>   `libnamespec.so` before searching for one called `libnamespec.a`. (By
>   convention, a .so extension indicates a shared library.) Note that
>   this behavior does not apply to `:filename`, which always specifies a
>   file called `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Michael's suggestion, but I will be tucking it away for future use.

The technique I use to *fully* control library linking is to avoid `-L`, `l`, `-Bstatic` and `-Bdynamic` altogether by fully specifying the library I want to use. The command would look similar to:

```
g++ main.cpp -o a.out /usr/local/lib/test.a
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp -o a.out /usr/local/lib/test.so
```

or

```
g++ main.cpp -o a.out /usr/local/lib/test.so.1.0.0
```